# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении после слова "поинтересоваться"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

Я понятия не имею, что следует поставить после слова "поинтересоваться". Единственное, что присутствует на уме — это запятая. Само предложение: "я задумалась и тут же захотела поинтересоваться с чего вдруг я стала идеалисткой".

Comment: После слова "идеолисткой" следует поставить двойку.

Comment: *Единственное, что присутствует на уме — это запятая* - это тоже неплохо.

Comment: Почему вы хотите закрыть вопрос? Чем вам непонятна его суть?

Comment: @ИгорьБолотов Вы не пробовали поинтересоваться историей правок вопроса? В подобных случаях это обычно помогает :)

Answer (score 2):

Это **сложноподчиненное предложение** (СПП)  с придаточным **изъяснительным**, союзное слово С ЧЕГО.

1. Основным знаком в СПП в этом случае является **запятая**.

*Я задумалась и тут же захотела поинтересоваться, **с чего** вдруг я стала идеалисткой*.

Однако в предложении такой конструкции лучше использовать **более сильные знаки** – тире или двоеточие.

2. Допускается поставить **тире,** если придаточное интонационно выделяется (подчеркивается пауза).

*Я задумалась и тут же захотела поинтересоваться – **с чего** вдруг я стала идеалисткой.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Интонационное отделение главной части от следующей за ней придаточной: *Вы спросите — **зачем** я пошёл на это?; А вы уверены — нужно **ли** это*?;

3. **Двоеточие** как неосновной знак тоже возможно (в этом случае допускается вопросительный знак, если вопрос интонационно выделен):

Я задумалась и тут же захотела поинтересоваться: **с чего** вдруг я стала идеалисткой?

Двоеточие ставится перед подчинительным союзом в тех случаях, когда в предшествующей главной части сложноподчиненного предложения содержится особое предупреждение о последующем разъяснении.

Интонационно это значительно увеличенная предупредительная пауза, понижение тона перед паузой.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=143#pp143

*Хаджи-Мурат сидел рядом в комнате и, хотя не понимал того, что говорили, понял то, что ему нужно было понять: **что** они спорили о нём* (Л. Т.);

4. Можно предложить еще один вариант **с частицей ЭТО**, тогда точно надо ставить тире:

*Я задумалась и тут же захотела поинтересоваться – **с чего** это я вдруг  стала идеалисткой*.

**ИДЕАЛИСТ**, -а; м. [франц. idéaliste] 1. Последователь идеалистической философии. Принадлежать к лагерю идеалистов. Быть последовательным идеалистом. 2. Тот, кто склонен идеализировать действительность; **мечтатель, непрактичный человек.** Ты просто и.! 3. Тот, кто всецело предан каким-л. высоким идеалам и руководствуется ими в своём поведении, жизни. И. жертвует многим во имя высокой идеи. Народник-идеалист. <Идеалистка, -и; мн. род. -ток, дат. -ткам; ж. (2-3 зн.). Идеалистский,